# Reg ex for single word

Tags: java, regex

I'm running a filter on content in a text file in Java. I've already taken out all punctuation. Now I need to take out certain frequent words.

I'm testing the string "I have a dream". My list of frequent words would filter our "I", "have", and "a", leaving me with "dream" only. My current code leaves me with "drem" filtering out the "a" in "a" and also in "dream".

I'm not sure how to attack this problem. Here is my current code.

```
public String removeStop (String file)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    String word;
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        word = scan.next();
        if(sw.contains(word)){
            file=file.replaceAll(word, "") ;
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

sw is an object that has a boolean function (contains) that tells me if "word" exists in the list of words I should filter out.

**QUESTION:** How do I filter out the word "a" without filtering 'a's from other words like "dream" which turns into "drem" when filtered? I thought this question was easy to infer from the explanation but i guess not. Hopefully this is explicit enough to not get closed

Comment: I guess you only want the list of non-common words, no text. You're scanning a String and at the same time modifying another one, this doesn't make much sense. Just scan and collect all words not contained in `sw` into a `StringBuilder` or a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're calling `replaceAll` you will still be left with many spaces OR other punctuation characters in the original string. I suggest using this:

```
file = file.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(\\W+|$)", "") ;
```

Where `\W` represents any non-word character and `\\b` is word-boundary.

PS: Also added `Pattern.quote` to escape the special regex symbols if any present in `word`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this :

```
file=file.replaceAll("\\b"+word+"\\b", "") ;
```

where `\b`  assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`.

**Sample code and output**

```
List<String> sw=new ArrayList();
sw.add("i");
sw.add("have");
sw.add("a");
String file="i have a dream";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String word;
while(scan.hasNext()){
   word = scan.next();
   if(sw.contains(word)){
         file=file.replaceAll("\\b"+word+"\\b", "") ;
    }
}
System.out.println(file.trim());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
dream
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uQ0iV6)**